# Converting Object[] into Hashmap

Tags: java, object, casting, hashmap

I have a function to  generate reports that receives the following arguments

```
public void generateReport(String[] headers, Object[] data)
```

I tried running the following code

```
HashMap<String, String>[] hMap = (HashMap<String, String>[]) data;

Collection c = hMap.values();
Iterator itr = c.iterator();    
while(itr.hasNext())
  System.out.println(itr.next());
```

**Output Error:**

```
cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol  : method values()
[ERROR] location: class java.util.HashMap<java.lang.String,java.lang.String>[]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`hMap` is an array of `HashMap`s, not a `HashMap`, so it has no `values()` method. You need `hMap[i].values()` to access the `values()` of the `i`'th `HashMap` in the array.

Comment: Now I get a cast error. ERROR ch.ralscha.extdirectspring.controller.RouterController - Error calling method: generateReport
java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.util.HashMap;

Comment: @ManuelFaria Cast each element of the array separately : `HashMap<String, String> hi = (HashMap<String, String>)data[i];`

Comment: @ManuelFaria You can't assign it to the `hMap` variable, since it's an array. You should assign it to a `HashMap` variable.

Comment: I think I assigned to a `HashMap` variable, just as a test, I've donet: `HashMap<String, String> hi = (HashMap<String, String>)data[1];
 System.out.println(hi[1].values());` and got the  `array required, but java.util.HashMap<java.lang.String,java.lang.String> found`error

Comment: @ManuelFaria Perhaps `data[1]` doesn't contain a HashMap object. Try to print `data` with `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(data));`

Comment: thank you. The cast didn't work beacuse data was a `LinkedHashMap` type, regards